# How do I receive Stack Overflow email notifications?

Tags: support, notifications, email

I have configured Notification email under Preferences, but I'm not receiving notifications at that email address.  I checked our spam filter and there are no emails from `do-not-reply@stackexchange.com` nor `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com`.  In fact, both are in my whitelist (just in case).

Comment: The setting says "Email me unread inbox messages **daily**" (there's other options, specifically 3 hours).  Have you gone that long with unread messages?  (Though I've never gotten emails about stuff either)

Comment: @Pokechu22 it is currently set to every 3 hours

Comment: I wonder if leaving the tab open in my browser makes the site think I'm actually staring at it and so I'd know there's a notification and then it doesn't email?

Comment: I think that's what happened: if you already clicked the inbox on the website before the set time to send you the email, stack overflow knew you already seen the notifications and therefore not sending you any emails.

Answer (score 1):

Check your spam filter for do-not-reply@stackexchange.email and do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email. Most (but not all) of our automated emails come from the .email domain, not the .com domain.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you inputted your correct email address. The system needs to confirm you own the inbox before sending messages. If you didn't see that message, is probable that you made a mistake in the email.