# Not getting notification by email when people reply to my posts

Tags: support, notifications, email

I am surprised that I am not getting any notification/alert by email when people respond/reply to my questions. Is it possible to get this information?

Comment: Do you have [that option enabled in your user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/9845428)?

Comment: Related: *[How do I receive Stack Overflow email notifications?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272501)* and *[Why am I not receiving email notifications?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357829)*

Comment: @Cody Gray: For broader applicability, the current user ID can be represented by *"current"* in Stack Exchange URLs (at least in some contexts): [https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current)

Comment: I’m aware, @Peter, but “current” links back to *my* account, rather than the other user’s account, which is inconvenient. Mod problems. :-)